# How to concat JS library files using gulp?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, gulp

Please check out my gist:
https://gist.github.com/flyspaceage/9e88716294df93c8eaece51fe413f7a3

All of my files seem to concat properly except the JS libraries.  Im using JS Socials, JS Scrollify, Headroom, JQuery 2.1.1, JS Slick.  The files concat into one minified file, but the libraries no longer work in production. I am writing my first Gulpfile, any suggestions focused on Gulp appreciated.

Comment: place your libraries in a different location. the reason why its not working is you are cleaning the dist directory, where the source files are.

Comment: so my libs directory should only contain JS that I wrote? Like my custom.js file? If i remove the JS libs then my dist directory will not have all files needed to deploy, is there a way to have it both ways?

Comment: you can create a different structure. scripts-> src (for files that you write) scripts->lib or scripts->vendor( for vendor specific). And update your gulp script respectively with the paths

Comment: Updated > https://gist.github.com/flyspaceage/9e88716294df93c8eaece51fe413f7a3.js

Comment: you can use pipe itself.

Comment: thanks! I was able to get all my scripts separated into two directories within dist/scripts/vendor and /custom/app.min.js

Comment: Cool.. have a nice day

Comment: does it matter what order my gulp tasks run in?  Do i need to run JS before SCSS or Sass?

Comment: order doesnt matter, sass will process .scss files and js will process .js files. so there is no dependency between them., Can you create a new question with the problem you are facing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your vendor libraries in a different location. The reason why its not working is you are cleaning the dist directory, where the source files are present.

Move all the scripts present in this directory to a folder 'vendor'

```
libs: ['dist/scripts/libs/jquery.headroom.js', 'dist/scripts/libs/headroom.js', 'dist/scripts/libs/jssocials.js', 'dist/scripts/libs/slick.min.js', 'dist/scripts/libs/jquery.scrollify.js'],
```

then change the folder path to vendor

```
libs: ['vendor/scripts/libs/jquery.headroom.js', 'vendor/scripts/libs/headroom.js', etc..,,,],
```

Comment: This allowed me to copy the files to another folder, however I need additional tasks defined to minify/uglify the scripts.

Comment: @FlySpaceAge: The comment deviates from the original requirement. Can you add this as a new question with the problems you are facing?